# Plot previous day levels misses the first candle of the day

Tags: pine-script

I am new to pine script coding. I am just trying to plot the previous day's high and the previous day's low in the current day's level.
It seems to draw/plot correctly for the rest of the day candles, but the levels/lines are missed on the first candle of the current day. How can that be corrected?

[image]

The levels seem to be drawn correctly after the first candle.
Same is the case with stepline as well.

[image]

Below is my pinescript code

```
 // This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
    // © sukanya_a
    //@version=4
    study("BNiftyLevels", overlay=true)
    PDH=security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high) 
    PDL=security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low) 
    plot(PDH[1],style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.red,linewidth=2)
    plot(PDL[1],style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.green,linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
study("BNiftyLevels", "BNL", overlay=true)

[h,l] = security(syminfo.ticker, "D", [high,low])

plot(h, style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.red,   linewidth=2)
plot(l, style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.green, linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was thinking " plot(PDH[1]"  in my code picks up the previous days levels. Guess that is wrong. I will have to recheck& learn my understanding of pinescript. Thanks for your answer.